# How to stub S3Transfer in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3, moto

Using botocore.stub and mock_s3 from moto I'm able to stub the boto3 S3 client like below,

```
from moto import mock_s3
from botocore.stub import Stubber

class TestS3(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock_s3
    def setUp(self):
        self.s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-west-1')
        self.stubber = Stubber(client=self.s3_client)
```

Then in the test functions I'm able to use add_client_error and add_response like below and add assertions as needed,

```
@mock_s3
def test_put_object_exception(self):
    self.stubber.add_client_error('put_object', service_error_code='500')
    with self.stubber:
        self.s3_service.put_object(data='/some/dummy/path', key='/some/dummy/key')
```

However in my S3 class, I'm using S3Transfer upload_file to upload files to S3, is there a way to mock S3Transfer(self.s3_client).upload_file method?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Dan Hook is very good.  If you also want to ensure that the requested upload text matches your expectations, you'll need a custom matcher object in place of the `ANY` variable.  It needs to have a custom `__eq__` (and thus also `__ne__`) implementation that works with the boto read chunk class.  Note that the code below uses the Python typing.

```
class ExpectedBinStream:
    """Expect a binary stream value."""
    def __init__(self, contents: bytes) -> None:
        self.contents = contents

    def __eq__(self, other: Any) -> bool:
        if not hasattr(other, 'read') or not callable(other.read):
            return False
        data = other.read()
        return self.contents == data

    def __ne__(self, other: Any) -> bool:
        return not self.__eq__(other)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return repr(self.contents)
```

This works because the stubber uses a simple equality check for the passed-in parameters.  The `ANY` value also takes advantage of this by always returning `True` for `__eq__` and `False` for `__ne__`.

Answer (score 0):

I found that stubbing put_object worked well. In the example 'test_file' does need to be a real file since S3Transfer checks to see if it exists.  S3Transfer will user other service methods if the file it transfers is large enough to justify multi-part uploads, but mocking that out starts to feel more like writing tests for S3Transfer than testing my own code.

```
import botocore.session
from botocore.stub import Stubber, ANY
from boto3.s3.transfer import S3Transfer
s3 = botocore.session.get_session().create_client('s3')
stubber = Stubber(s3)

BUCKET='mock_bucket'
KEY='mock_key'                       
put_object_response = {   'ETag': '"14fe4f49fffffffffff9afbaaaaaaaa9"',
    'ResponseMetadata': {   'HTTPHeaders': {   'content-length': '0',
                                               'date': 'Wed, 08 Apr 2020 '
                                                       '20:35:42 GMT',
                                               'etag': '"14fe4f49fffffffffff9afbaaaaaaaa9"',
                                               'server': 'AmazonS3',
                                               },
                            'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
                            'HostId': 'GEHrJmjk76Ug/clCVUwimbmIjTTb2S4kU0lLg3Ylj8GKrAIsv5+S7AFb2cRkCLd+mpptmxfubLM=',
                            'RequestId': 'A8FFFFFFF84C3A77',
                            'RetryAttempts': 0},
    'VersionId': 'Dbc0gbLVEN4N5F4oz7Hhek0Xd82Mdgyo'}
stubber.add_response('put_object', put_object_response,expected_params= {'Body': ANY, 'Bucket':BUCKET,'Key':KEY})
stubber.activate()
transfer = S3Transfer(s3)
transfer.upload_file('test_file', BUCKET,KEY)
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, the expected parameter was `<ANY>` for the Body but the received was `<s3transfer.utils.ReadFileChunk>`